# Send SMS text message using SSIS package

Tags: ssis, sms

What feature is available within SSIS to sent text messages? If it is not one,  what other options are available?

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [Send Mail task](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142165.aspx) and treat it just like sending an email. The only thing you will have to worry about is how dynamic this needs to be, since the cell phone number address has to match up with the provider.

So if I want to send a message to a cell phone that is on Verizon, I would use `3334445555@vtext.com`. A good listing that shows [most all providers can be found here](http://www.emailtextmessages.com/).

Comment: What if I do not know the provider for each cell phone number ?

Comment: You are pretty much out of luck. You will have to program around an API that lets you look up the provider based on the number. [CarrierLookup](https://www.carrierlookup.com/index.php) is one that offers an API.